# Facebook Login Api is not working on mobile view

Tags: javascript, facebook, responsive-design, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook's javascript login API. The function is working on desktop view but the same function is not working on mobile view. On mobile view page is getting reload on function call. Here is the javascript function. What could be the possible problem?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxx',
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
        // the session
        xfbml: false, // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.3' // use version 2.2
    });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fblogin() {

    var out = '<div align="center" class="loadingGif">';
    out += '<img src="/image/31.gif"/>';
    out += '<p>Logging In...Please Wait</p>';
    out += '</div>';
    document.getElementById("loginModalContent").innerHTML = out;


    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {

            var userId = 0;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                console.log("Respose is:" + JSON.stringify(response));
            }, {
                scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends,user_about_me,user_birthday'
            });
        }
    });
}
```